# Error Handling still throws run-time error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem catching an error, basically I have a form that the user selects months to open a form, if no months is selected then the `CreateSQL` SQL query will throw a run time error as there is nothing inside the `IN` in the `WHERE` clause.

So once an error occurs the `MsgBox` does not even pop up and just throws a Run-Time Error '3075'. If i remove the `Resume Exit_Error` and `Exit_Error` then the `MsgBox` does pop up but then after it throws the Run-Time Error again. Am i doing something wrong here when trying to catch the error?

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

On Error GoTo Error_handler

Dim months As String

months = IIf([Forms]![Select]![January].Value = True, ",1", "")& _
    IIf([Forms]![Select]![February].Value = True, ",2", "")
    ...(And so on for each month)

months = Mid(months, 2)

CreateSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE MONTH (Date_Happened) IN (" & months & ")"

Me.RecordSource = CreateSQL

Exit_Error:
    Exit Sub


Error_handler:
    MsgBox "Please select an appropriate date (Month/s AND Year)"
    Resume Exit_Error

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger to confirm that the error is being raised inside this event handler?  The obvious solution would be to add validation logic to make sure you aren't building bad SQL instead of relying on the error handler.

Comment: Haven't been able to use the Access debugger for some reason, pressing F8 and going Debug>Step Into doesnt do anything at all. But works in the Excel debugger, no idea why.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the first line of code, then open the report.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by having an empty element in your query `IN(,1)`.  I use create functions to return my query strings so that I can test my queries in the query designer.

### Error:

[image]

### Output:

[image]

### Code:

```
Function getDateHappenQuery() As String
    Const BASE_SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE MONTH (Date_Happened) IN ( @months )"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String

    With [Forms]![Select]
        For i = 1 To 12
            If .Controls(MonthName(i)).Value Then s = s & i & ","
        Next
    End With

    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    If Len(s) Then getDateHappenQuery = Replace(BASE_SQL, "@months", s)

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry I missed out on one line of code and I made the edit on original post `months = Mid(months, 2)`. This means there is no empty element. The error throws because if no month is selected in the form then the query will show `WHERE MONTH (Date_Happened) IN ()` because the `()` is empty it throws the error. I just want to throw a MsgBox to tell users to select months without a run-time error being thrown in the VBA Code.

Comment: I don't think that you can escape the error.  You will have to test the validity of the query before you run it.  Something like `If len(months) = 0 then Goto 
Error_handler`

Comment: I was leaning towards this, I ended up going `If Len(months) = 0 Then months = "0" MsgBox "Please select an appropriate date (Year AND Month/s)"` Just because going to `Exit Sub` still throws a bunch of errors. This way it just produces an empty report and prompts the `MsgBox`.

Comment: You could also have a label on the report that will become visible if the recordcount = 0.  You might want to consider showing all the months if none are selected; it'll save the user from clicking 12 boxes or you from creating a select all button.

Comment: Good ideas! I'll probably implement some of those ideas.